# Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem Solve $\int_{C} e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ where $c$ is $|z| = 1$

Tags: calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

The answer for the above question is given as $0$ in my college textbook. But when I read the actual theorem, it is written that the function must be analytic everywhere inside and on the curve. However here the exponential function is not analytic at the point $z=0$. Then how does the integral become $0$? Please bear with me as I am a beginner.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_C e^{\frac{1}{z}}dz$?

Comment: It is not $0$. The value is $2\pi i$.

Comment: yes you are right saluta sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry Geetha i dont understand how z needs to be 2\pi i to be non analytic i thought it should be z=0 could you please elaborate more

Comment: To do this with Cauchy's integral theorem, you could use the fact that this is analytic **outside** the contour.  If you have not done that form of Cauchy, prove it by changing variables $w=1/z$ to convert to the case where it is analytic **inside** the contour.